# How to get a rotated, zoomed and panned image from an UIImageView at its full resolution?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an UIImageView which can be rotated, panned and scaled with gesture recognisers. As a result it is **cropped** in its enclosing view.
Everything is working fine but I don't know how to save the **visible part** of the picture in its **full resolution**. It's not a screen grab.

I know I get the UIImage straight from the visible content of the UIImageView but it is limited to the resolution of the screen.

I assume that I have to do the same transformations on the UIImage and crop it. IS there an easy way to do that?

**Update**:
For example, I have an UIImageView with an image in high resolution, let's say a 8MP iPhone 4s camera photo, which is transformed with gestures, so it becomes scaled, rotated and moved around in its enclosing view. Obviously there is some cropping going on so only a part of the image is displayed. There is a huge difference between the displayed screen resolution and the underlining image resolution, I need an image in the image resolution. The UIImageView is in **UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit**, but a solution with UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill is also fine.

This is my code:

```
- (void)rotatePiece:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer rotation]);
        [gestureRecognizer setRotation:0];
    }
}

- (void)scalePiece:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer scale], [gestureRecognizer scale]);
        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];
    }
}

-(void)panGestureMoveAround:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
{
    UIView *piece = [gestureRecognizer view];

    //We pass in the gesture to a method that will help us align our touches so that the pan and pinch will seems to originate between the fingers instead of other points or center point of the UIView    
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[piece superview]];
        [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y+translation.y)];
        [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];
    } else if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        //Put the code that you may want to execute when the UIView became larger than certain value or just to reset them back to their original transform scale
    }
}


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    // if the gesture recognizers are on different views, don't allow simultaneous recognition
    if (gestureRecognizer.view != otherGestureRecognizer.view)
        return NO;

    // if either of the gesture recognizers is the long press, don't allow simultaneous recognition
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]] || [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
        return NO;

    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
    faceImageView.image = appDelegate.faceImage;

    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotatePiece:)];
    [faceImageView addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture];
    [rotationGesture setDelegate:self];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scalePiece:)];
    [pinchGesture setDelegate:self];
    [faceImageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureMoveAround:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [faceImageView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

    [appDelegate fadeObject:moveIcons StartAlpha:0 FinishAlpha:1 Duration:2];
    currentTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:4.0f target:self selector:@selector(fadeoutMoveicons) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer: currentTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}
```

Comment: we need to know what contentMode you set for the image view, so that we can compute the correct crop rect for the image easier

Comment: @phix23 the content mode is UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following code creates a snapshot of the enclosing view (superview of `faceImageView` with `clipsToBounds` set to `YES`) using a calculated scale factor.

It assumes that the content mode of faceImageView is `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` and that the frame of faceImageView is set to the enclosingView's bounds.

```
- (UIImage *)captureView {

    float imageScale = sqrtf(powf(faceImageView.transform.a, 2.f) + powf(faceImageView.transform.c, 2.f));    
    CGFloat widthScale = faceImageView.bounds.size.width / faceImageView.image.size.width;
    CGFloat heightScale = faceImageView.bounds.size.height / faceImageView.image.size.height;
    float contentScale = MIN(widthScale, heightScale);
    float effectiveScale = imageScale * contentScale;

    CGSize captureSize = CGSizeMake(enclosingView.bounds.size.width / effectiveScale, enclosingView.bounds.size.height / effectiveScale);

    NSLog(@"effectiveScale = %0.2f, captureSize = %@", effectiveScale, NSStringFromCGSize(captureSize));

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(captureSize, YES, 0.0);        
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1/effectiveScale, 1/effectiveScale);
    [enclosingView.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Depending on the current transform the resulting image will have a different size. For example when you zoom in, the size gets smaller. You can also set `effectiveScale` to a constant value in order to get an image with a constant size.

Your gesture recognizer code does not limit the scale factor, i.e. you can zoom out/in without being limited. That can be very dangerous! My capture method can output really large images when you've zoomed out very much.

If you have zoomed out the background of the captured image will be black. If you want it to be transparent, you must set the opaque-parameter of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to `NO`.

Comment: Great solution - perfect! I've been looking for this for ages! all other solutions just take a screenshot effectively which is rubbish quality

Comment: Tried yor code, but its not working for zoomed image, I am using scrollview as enclosingView and faceImageView is my imageview inside scrollview. it is giving blank image. without zoom it is workiing properly. Can you please help.

Answer (score 3):

Why capturing the view if you have the original image? Just apply the transformations to it. Something like this may be a start:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"<# original #>"];

CIImage *cimage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];

// build the transform you want
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[self.faceImageView valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
CGFloat scale = [(NSNumber *)[self.faceImageView valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.scale"] floatValue];    
t = CGAffineTransformConcat(t, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale));
t = CGAffineTransformConcat(t, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle));

// create a new CIImage using the transform, crop, filters, etc.
CIImage *timage = [cimage imageByApplyingTransform:t];

// draw the result
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef imageRef = [context createCGImage:timage fromRect:[timage extent]];
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

// save to disk
NSData *png = UIImagePNGRepresentation(result);
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/result.png"];
if (png && [png writeToFile:path atomically:NO]) {
    NSLog(@"\n%@", path);
}
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

You can easily crop the output if that's what you want (see `-[CIImage imageByCroppingToRect]`  or take into account the translation, apply a Core Image filter, etc. depending on what are your exact needs.

Comment: I want visible part of image inside UIImageview. this is giving me same image like original. can you please help. Structure is like UIImageview inside UIscrollview to give zoom effect. I want only that part which is visible  with resolution quality.

Comment: I have same problem like Vibhooti had , I am cropping Scrollview visible rect from image (Zoomed) and it is working also but  with  no rotation , but how to take rotation in account here ?,As i am converting scrollview visible point to image (if image rotated then it is not possible use frame :( )  I am struggling since 2 weeks ,if you could help me then it would be great , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Bellow Code Capture Your Current View ...

```
- (UIImage *)captureView {

    CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.yourImage.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;

}
```

I think you want to save the display screen and use it ,so i post this code...
Hope,this help you...
:)

Comment: read the question, Q asked especially not for screen grab because it is limited to the device resolution.

Comment: I can capture screen, no problem, but I need a solution with full resolution. P.s. your code does not even capture in retina resolution.

Comment: I think what @Tibidabo really needs is a way to compute the visible crop rect  in the **original** image, which may have a smaller or larger size than the image view frame. This crop rect also can have a rotation. The crop rect depends essentially on 3 properties of the imageView: bounds, contentMode and transform. Creating an image context is the right way to cut out the visible portion of the original image, but thats the easy part of it.

Comment: @phix23 Thanks. I know how it should be done it, but I just don't want to spend time implementing and debugging a pretty standard solution when lot's of people already done it. I have already done the panning and scaling part, that was easy.

Comment: @ParasJoshi Sorry I can't see how it could work. The rect created does not take into account scale, rotation or panning of the image view.

Comment: then try to use rect with [self.yourImage bounds]; just try i miss this thing but once try it may your problem solved 
:)