# Why PNG image got double size after taking screenshot of UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimagepngrepresentation

I am able to take screenshot from `UIView` at iPhone 6 with below code: -

Here I have printed 2 logs. First gives me image size `{375, 667}` but after converting it to PNG format it gives me image size `{750, 1334}`.

I know that it's converting it for the retina display. Each point is represented by 2 pixels on the screen so the saved image is double the resolution.

But I need image size `{375, 667}` with PNG format.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSLog(@"Image Size: %@", image);  // Image Size: <UIImage: 0x1700880c0>, {375, 667}

    NSData* imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    UIImage* pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pngImage, nil, nil, nil);

    NSLog(@"PNG Image Size: %@", pngImage);  // PNG Image Size: <UIImage: 0x174087760>, {750, 1334}

    return image;
}
```

Big Image:-
[image]

Small Image:-

[image]

Comment: [UIScreen mainScreen].scale says it all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS : Save image with custom resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432169/ios-save-image-with-custom-resolution)

Answer (score 1):

just to not get a bad quality you can create an image with screen scale

but when you load you can use this

```
CGFloat screenScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
if (screenScale != img.scale) {
    img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage scale:screenScale    orientation:img.imageOrientation];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdelahad Darwish. It gives me Image Size: {375, 667} in NSLog but when I am saving it using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum then it again gives me image dimension {750, 1334} in Photos(Camera Roll). Please help. I need Image Size: {375, 667} in PNG with good quality of image.

Comment: see your code you can compress image  with this `    UIImage* pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData scale:1];`

Comment: I tried UIImage* pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData scale:1]; but it gives same image dimension {750, 1334} in Photos(Camera Roll).

Answer (score 0):

Change the scale to 1 instead of `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 1);
```

Comment: I have also checked with this it gives me PNG image size {375, 667} but problem is that it reduces image quality. Image got blurred. I need PNG image as same size as JPG with same quality. Please help.

Comment: I have attached 2 images. Big with [UIScreen mainScreen].scale and small is with 1.  Here I am getting quality issue in small image.

Comment: How can I fix it also? Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: @AsifRaza Keep scale to original, Try this, use this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/613380/1025063