# Rotation gesture for UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have implemented a rotation gesture for `UIImageView`.

Here is the Code that I implemented:

```
- (IBAction)rotaehandler:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(sender.view.transform, sender.rotation);
}
```

I connected `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` to `UIImageView`.
It works but, How can i rotate image form its center.

Comment: Enter the concept of ["division"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)).

Comment: @ShaaberAli If you read the Wikipedia article I linked to, you'll see this basic mathematical operation explained pretty well.

Comment: `CGAffineTransformRotate(sender.view.transform, sender.rotation / SOME_CONSTANT)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGFloat initialRotation = atan2f(sender.view.transform.b-somefloat, sender.view.transform.a-somefloat);

 CGFloat newRotation = initialRotation + sender.rotation;

 sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRotation);
```

try above code

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
- (IBAction)rotaehandler:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender
    {


        if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [sender state] ==  
                 UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
        {
            [sender view].transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([[sender view] transform],  
                                                                [sender rotation]);

             NSLog(@"Rotate : %f",[gestureRecognizer rotation]);
             [sender setRotation:0];
         }
    }
```

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104042/how-to-get-a-rotated-zoomed-and-panned-image-from-an-uiimageview-at-its-full-re


this will helps u